# Unbound local variable error when importing signal?

Tags: python

I am importing `signal` at the beginning of my file. I then wish to use this in a function like so:

```
 os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

I get an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'signal' referenced before assignment.
```

If I instead `import signal` inside the function I get no such problem, why is this happening?

EDIT: example code

```
import signal
def func():
    if args.kill: # Never triggered
        import signal
        os.kill(int(args.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
    elif args.name:
        os.kill(int(args.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Show some proper code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You are most likely assigning **to** `signal` in the same function.

Comment: In particular, show a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Or at least a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not sure why you could not reproduce but nevertheless importing globally works fine.

Comment: @Paul: No, I spotted the problem and reproduced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a name in a function is *also* an assignment; essentially your sample could be further reduced to this:

```
def function(arg1, arg2):
    if False:
        import signal

    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

This makes `signal` a local variable in the function, and Python won't look for the global name.

The `import signal` line makes `signal` a local name, but because the line is never executed, `signal` is never bound and the exception is thrown.

Remove *all* `import signal` lines from the function, or move it out of the conditional to be imported unconditionally (and thus always bind `signal`).

Comment: This is not the case Martijn and that is why I do not understand, I joked that you would answer in 3 seconds, thanks :) I see the only other case of signal being used is that it is imported a  different function to use os.kill like I am. Added way before mine and that code path is not triggered

Comment: @Paul: Show us the function, then.

Comment: @Paul: You still have a local name `signal` in your function; please show us the *full* function.

Comment: @Paul: There is only one way a `UnboundLocalVariable` is thrown: when you are referencing a local name in the function before it is bound to. That means that Python thinks you are using the name `signal` **somewhere** in the function as an assignment target.

Comment: I have added an example of the problem now.

Comment: @Paul: In your example, the `import signal` inside the function is considered an assignment to `signal`. If it doesn't get triggered, the local variable is unbound.

Comment: @user2357112 that code is never called, but it still affects it, is that the case? It is never imported in that code, as it is not called

Comment: @Paul: The presence of an assignment inside a function determines whether a variable is local. It doesn't matter whether the assignment is run.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, that didn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your second

```
import signal
```

in the function is the problem. Omit it.

It is just a local assignment as anything else: the module object will be assigned to the *local* name `signal`.

You can have it twice in a function - it is then local twice and the second `import` will do nothing, or you can it have once at the top of the function, but you cannot have it once buried deeply inside and only executed sometimes.

In your case, the error will occur `if not args.kill`. Then the assignment will not happen, but the local name doesn't cease to exist.

Compare this to

```
import signal as global_signal
signal = global_signal
def func():
    if args.kill: # Never triggered
        signal = global_signal
        os.kill(int(args.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
    elif args.name:
        os.kill(int(args.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

- it is essentially the same, but with additional identifiers.